# Sonarqube report in graph/chart for time (weekly/daily) and number of issues

Tags: sonarqube

I want to display a graphical report based on time (weekly/daily) which shows that what is the status of static code analysis over the period of time. E.g. vertical bar will denote number of issue and horizontal will display the time day/month/week. This will help to keep an watch of code quality easily over the period of time (something like burn down chart of scrum). Can someone help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

The 5.1.2 issues search web service includes parameters which let you query for issues by creation date. Your best best is to use AJAX requests to get the data you need and build your widget from there.

Note that you can query iteratively across a date range using `&p=1&ps=1` (page=1 and page size=1) to limit the volume of data flying around, and just mine the `total` value in the top level of the response to get your answer.

[Here's an example on Nemo](http://nemo.sonarqube.org/api/issues/search?p=1&ps=1&createdAfter=2015-09-23&createdBefore=2015-09-24)